# Changing character spacing in an input field with an underline below each character

Tags: html, css

I need to put a space between the 3rd and 4th characters of the code, like on the layout.

[image]

How can i do this?

```css
.code-input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 120px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #818181 0, #818181 16px, transparent 16px, transparent 18px, #818181 18px, #818181 34px, transparent 34px, transparent 36px, #818181 36px, #818181 54px, transparent 54px, transparent 62px) 0 100%/ 120px 1px no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Inter', monospace;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.code-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input class='code-input' maxLength='6' defaultValue='' />
```

Comment: Have you tried with some input mask libraries? Or with two inputs?

Comment: No, I thought about it, but I don’t understand how to then validate the code from two inputs with backend.